# How to create an ER diagram using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

### The creativity time in the code has arrived!

I would like to make an [Entity–relationship model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) (ER model) using `tikzpicture` environment.

I have found that `TikZ` actually have a library for that (`\usetikzlibrary{er}`) and other stuff, but actually I do not need colors or weird shapes to create the following generic ER diagram:

[image: The ER diagram I want]

[The `er` manual](https://www.guitex.org/home/images/ArsTeXnica/AT015/drawing-ER-diagrams-with-TikZ.pdf) says nothing about create relations nor label around the entities, so it is a difficulty for me.

### General considerations

- There are four possibilities of relationship (with their combinations at the other extreme): [image: Types of relationship]
- An entity can have one, several or no attributes, one below the other (letter size smaller than the text of the entity).
- An entity must have coordinates to add `is in` labels (smaller size than the attributes). Pay attention the the labels between `Entity C` and its sub-entities.
- Relationships between entities may have folds/orthogonality.
- Attributes must have `\scriptsize` font.

**Make it happen!**

### EDIT (MWE ADDED)

Thanks to [CarLaTeX's useful comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462914/how-to-create-an-er-diagram-using-tikzpicture-environment#comment1164499_462914) I was able to advance a little more:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

% code for "one to omany", etc. is taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141797/101651
\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{crow's foot}{crow's foot}
{
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.5\pgflinewidth}%
}
{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.6pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-9\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-13\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{9\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{-6pt}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{-6pt}}%  
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{6pt}}% 
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{omany}{omany}
{
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.5\pgflinewidth}%
}
{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.6pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-9\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-13\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{9\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%  
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-6pt}{-6pt}}% 
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{-11.5pt}{0}} {3.5pt}
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{one}{one}
{
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.5\pgflinewidth}%
}
{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.6pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-6pt}{-6pt}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-6pt}{-6pt}}%  
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-6pt}{6pt}}% 
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{-6pt}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{-6pt}}%  
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{6pt}}%    
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{%
    pics/entity/.style n args={3}{code={%
        \node[draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        text height=1.5ex,
        ] (#1)
        {#2 \nodepart{second}
            \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{8.5em}}
                #3
            \end{tabular}
        };%
    }},
    pics/entitynoatt/.style n args={2}{code={%
        \node[draw,
        text height=1.5ex,
        ] (#1)
        {#2};%
    }},
    zig zag to/.style={
        to path={(\tikztostart) -| ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) |- (\tikztotarget)}
    },
    zig zag to/.default=0.5,   
    one to one/.style={
        one-one, zig zag to
    },
    one to oone/.style={            % I do not how to make "one to Optional-one" rel
        one-one, zig zag to
    },
    one to many/.style={
        one-crow's foot, zig zag to,
    },
    one to omany/.style={
        one-omany, zig zag to
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pic {entity={A}{Entity A}{%
                attribute 1 \\
                attribute 2 \\        
                ... \\
                attribute i
            }};
            \pic[right=7em of A] {entity={AB}{Entity A for Entity B}{%
                attribute 1 \\
                attribute 2
            }};
            \pic[right=7em of AB] {entity={B}{Entity B}{%
                attribute 1 \\
                attribute 2 \\        
                ... \\
                attribute i
            }};
            \pic[below=16ex of B] {entity={C}{Entity C}{%
                attribute 1    
            }};
            \pic[below=15ex of AB] {entitynoatt={C1}{Entity C\_1}};
            \pic[below=9ex of C1] {entitynoatt={C2}{Entity C\_2}};
            \draw[one to omany] (A.east) -- node[above]{\footnotesize is in} (AB.west);
            \draw[one to omany] (B.west) -- node[above]{\footnotesize is in} (AB.east);
            \draw[one to one] (B.south) -- node[right]{\footnotesize is in} (C.north);
            \draw[one to oone] (C.west) -| ($(C.west)!.5!(C1.east)$) |- node[above]{\footnotesize is in} (C1.east);  % Make "oone" rel
            \draw[one to oone] (C.west) -| ($(C.west)!.5!(C2.east)$) |- node[below]{\footnotesize is in} (C2.east);  % Make "oone" rel
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: How far I got]

However, there are some things that I would like to modify:

- Add new lines in entity's `#1` parameter (label).
- Make white circle instead of transparent in optional cardinality.
- When two curved relations find in the same point reduce the thickness in that part, since from a distance it seems thicker: [image: Reduce thickness].
- Make "one to Optional one" and "Optional one to Optional one" relationships.
- Position the labels that are between relationships on the outside edge of the entities.

[image: What I want after CarLaTeX's comment]

### Some links

- [Online ER diagram creator for free](https://www.draw.io/)
- [Git of the `er` library](https://github.com/cfiandra/er-oo) ([-> PDF manual](https://github.com/cfiandra/er-oo/blob/master/er-oo.pdf))
- ["Drawing ER diagrams with TikZ"](https://www.guitex.org/home/images/ArsTeXnica/AT015/drawing-ER-diagrams-with-TikZ.pdf)
- [Example: Entity-relationship diagram](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/er-diagram/)
- [CarLaTeX's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462914/how-to-create-an-er-diagram-using-tikzpicture-environment#comment1164499_462914)

Thanks!

Comment: manooooh, start from this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367337/101651

Comment: @CarLaTeX o.O I have not see that question before. I will take a look, thanks!

Comment: As it is currently phrased your questions sounds as if you want someone to write a package for you (I don't want to cite the typical we-are-no-do-it-for-me-service-response). What have you tried?

Comment: @TeXnician thanks for your comment! I thought it once, but then I realized that there are a lot of answered questions with a lot of lines code so this time it was not going to be the same (here are only rectangles, lines and text). I do not post an MWE because I did not find anything similar to what I am looking for until I look over the link of CarLaTeX and it has some similar things. Then I will try to do something.

Comment: @CarLaTeX done! Please see the edit.

Comment: Do you want to get the output of the upper picture or make the red corrections?

Comment: @marmot I want the output of the last picture (without arrows, red color, etc.)!

Comment: So no curly brace where the lines of C_1 and C_2 join to C?

Comment: @marmot right, as simple as possible.

Comment: Well, just a black dot instead of the complicated diagram may be the simplest... but not necessarily what you want. ;-)

Comment: Why do you use the `pdflscape` package with `\begin{landscape}...\end{landscape}` and not the native option of the article class `\documentclass[landscape]{article}`?

Comment: @AndréC because I did not know that. If that means that each page should be rotated, it's not what I'm looking for, I just need this page rotated.

Comment: @manooooh Yes, the option `\documentclass[landscape]{article}` means that the entire article will be landscape.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Add new lines in entity's #1 parameter (label)

Just declare a `text width=...` and then you can use `\\` in the node description.

> Make white circle instead of transparent in optional cardinality.

Done with `\pgfsetfillcolor{white}` and `\pgfusepathqfillstroke`.

> When two curved relations find in the same point reduce the thickness
>   in that part, since from a distance it seems thicker: Reduce
>   thickness.

Indeed, it *is* thicker because it is drawn twice, I did a trick to draw it only once (the second path is drawn only till the intersection).

> Make "one to Optional one" and "Optional one to Optional one"
>   relationships.

Created `one to oone`, `oone to none` and `oone to oone`, more or less copied from a [previous answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393568/101651), which was copied, too, from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141969/101651).

> Position the labels that are between relationships on the outside edge
>   of the entities.

Since the labels are not strictly related with the path, just put some nodes in the desired position.

> Attributes must have `\scriptsize` font.

Added `[font=\scriptsize]` to `\nodepart`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

% code for "one to omany", etc. is taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141797/101651
\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{crow's foot}{crow's foot}
{
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.5\pgflinewidth}%
}
{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.6pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-9\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-13\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{9\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{-6pt}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{-6pt}}%  
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{6pt}}% 
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{omany}{omany}
{
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.5\pgflinewidth}%
}
{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.6pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-9\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-13\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{9\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%  
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-6pt}{-6pt}}% 
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{-11.5pt}{0}} {3.5pt}
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke%
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{one}{one}
{
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.5\pgflinewidth}%
}
{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.6pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-6pt}{-6pt}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-6pt}{-6pt}}%  
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-6pt}{6pt}}% 
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{-6pt}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{-6pt}}%  
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-8pt}{6pt}}%    
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{oone}{oone}
{
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.5\pgflinewidth}%
}
{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.6pt%
    %\advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.25\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
     \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-4pt}{-6pt}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-4pt}{-6pt}}%  
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-4pt}{6pt}}% 
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{-11.5pt}{0}} {3.5pt}
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke%
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{%
    mylabel/.style={font=\footnotesize},
    pics/entity/.style n args={3}{code={%
        \node[draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        text height=1.5ex,
        text width=8.5em,
        text centered
        ] (#1)
        {#2 \nodepart[font=\scriptsize]{second}
            \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9em}}
                #3
            \end{tabular}
        };%
    }},
    pics/entitynoatt/.style n args={2}{code={%
        \node[draw,
        text height=1.5ex,
        text width=8.5em,
        text centered
        ] (#1)
        {#2};%
    }},
    zig zag to/.style={
        to path={(\tikztostart) -| ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) |- (\tikztotarget)}
    },
    zig zag to/.default=0.5,   
    one to one/.style={
        one-one, zig zag to
    },
    one to oone/.style={% One to Optional-one
        one-oone, zig zag to
    },
    oone to none/.style={% Optional-one to none
        oone-, zig zag to
    },
    oone to oone/.style={% Optional one to Optional-one
        oone-oone, zig zag to
    },
    one to many/.style={
        one-crow's foot, zig zag to,
    },
    one to omany/.style={
        one-omany, zig zag to
    },
    one to none/.style={
        one-, zig zag to
    },    
}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pic {entity={A}{Entity A}{%
                attribute 1 \\
                attribute 2 \\        
                ... \\
                attribute i
            }};
            \pic[right=7em of A] {entity={AB}{{Entity A \\ for \\ Entity B}}{%
                attribute 1 \\
                attribute 2
            }};
            \pic[right=7em of AB] {entity={B}{Entity B}{%
                attribute 1 \\
                attribute 2 \\        
                ... \\
                attribute i
            }};
            \pic[below=16ex of B] {entity={C}{Entity C}{%
                attribute 1    
            }};
            \pic[below=15ex of AB] {entitynoatt={C1}{Entity C\textunderscore 1}};
            \pic[below=9ex of C1] {entitynoatt={C2}{Entity C\textunderscore 2}};
            \draw[one to omany] (A.east) -- (AB.west);
            \node[mylabel, anchor=south east] at (A.north east) {is in};
            \draw[one to omany] (B.west) -- (AB.east);
            \node[mylabel, anchor=south west] at (B.north west) {is in};
            \draw[one to one] (B.south) -- (C.north);
            \node[mylabel, anchor=south west] at (B.south east) {is in};
            \node[mylabel, anchor=north west] at (C.north east) {is in};
            %From section 13.3 of the TikZ manual, (2,1 |- 3,4) and (3,4 -| 2,1) both yield the same as (2,4) 
            \coordinate (mymiddle) at ($(C.west)!.5!(C1.east)$);
            \coordinate (mylink) at (C.west -| mymiddle);
            \draw[one to oone] (C.west) -| (mymiddle) node[mylabel, above=10pt]{is in} |- (C1.east);  % Make "oone" rel
            \draw[oone to none] (C2.east) -|  node[mylabel, below=2pt]{is in} (mylink);
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your code?

Comment: @AndréC Done. I replied to the OP's questions.

Comment: It was just what I wanted, clear and easy to understand. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

I answer too late to get the bounty, but @CarLaTeX deserves it because she has done a lot of research for you.

Your question and the comments of the eminent contributors motivated me to solve your problem. And I thank you for that.

First, it is useless to use the `pdflscape` package  to have a page in `landscape` format: it is a native option of the article class: `\documentclass[landscape]{article}`

#### Transcription of the old code v 1.18 with the new 3.0.1a:

The operation `\pgfarrowsdeclare` of your code is not documented in version 3.0.1a of TikZ. This operation can be found on page 317 of manual `1.18` (available [here](http://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) for download).

I transcribed his code with the syntax of the `3.0.1a` manual, the operation is now called `\pgfdeclarearrow` (the name is reversed, see page 1017 of the 3.0.1a manual).

I noticed that this old code is clumsy: many operations are not necessary at all and do nothing. I deleted all the commented lines since it is useless to precede a `\pgfpathlineto` with a `\pgfpathmoveto`. The `\pgfpathlineto` is enough.

```
    \pgfarrowsdeclare{omany}{omany}
{
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}%
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.5\pgflinewidth}%
}
{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.6pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-9\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-13\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{9\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
 %   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%  
 %   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
  %  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-6pt}{-6pt}}% 
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{-11.5pt}{0}} {3.5pt}
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
}
```

I thus cleaned the code of all relationships arrows.

#### The arrow now changes proportion according to the thickness of the line.

I use a TeX registry called `\arrowsize` for that.

From now on, the arrow increases slightly depending on the thickness of the line `\pgflinewidth`.

```
\arrowsize=0.5pt%
\advance\arrowsize by .25\pgflinewidth
```

#### The problem of the thickness of the line between `C` and `C1  C2`:

It is due to a calculation error you made in the placement of `C1` and `C2` because the middle of these two nodes is not right in the middle of  `C`.

So, to avoid complicated calculations, I built your diagram differently: I placed `C1` and `C2` **relative** to `C` and **not** as you did relative to `AB`.

```
\pic[above left=2ex and 7em of C] {entitynoatt={C1}{Entity C\_1}};
\pic[below left=2ex and 7em of C] {entitynoatt={C2}{Entity C\_2}};
```

To place the labels, I created a pic called `is in` whose argument is the `angle` of its `anchor`.

```
is in/.pic={\node[label=#1:is in,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt]{};}
```

#### Entity relationship diagram symbols

As I didn't know about entity relationship diagram symbol, I did a search on the net. It appears that the symbols are not standardized and therefore we have full latitude to design them to our liking.

Thus, on this [site](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878359/%2FArticles%2F878359%2FData-Modelling-using-ERD-with-Crow-Foot-Notation), they are drawn as follows:

[image: er1]

On [this one](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/er-diagrams) as well:

[image: er2]

Etc.

#### That's my proposal:

I drew lines of different thicknesses to visualize the variation in the length of the arrow. The **names** of the arrows are written **above**, the **line size** below.

[image: my proposal]

I just called them:

- `mmany` for "mandatory many";
- `omany` for "optional many";
- `mone` for "mandatory one";
- `oone` for "optional one"

Their code is below:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\pgfdeclarearrow{ %page 1020 of 3.0.1a manual
name = mmany,
parameters = { },
setup code = { },
drawing code = {
    \newdimen\arrowsize%
    \arrowsize=0.5pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \advance\arrowsize by .25\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-9\arrowsize}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-13\arrowsize}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{9\arrowsize}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-19\arrowsize}{-10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-19\arrowsize}{10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
    },
defaults = { }
}

\pgfdeclarearrow{ %page 1020 of 3.0.1a manual
name = omany,
parameters = { },
setup code = { },
drawing code = {
    \newdimen\arrowsize%
    \arrowsize=0.5pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \advance\arrowsize by .25\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-9\arrowsize}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-13\arrowsize}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{9\arrowsize}}%
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{-19\arrowsize}{0}} {6\arrowsize}%
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke%
    },
defaults = { }
}

\pgfdeclarearrow{ %page 1020 of 3.0.1a manual
name = mone,
parameters = { },
setup code = { },
drawing code = {
    \newdimen\arrowsize%
    \arrowsize=0.5pt%%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \advance\arrowsize by .25\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-9\arrowsize}{-10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-9\arrowsize}{10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-19\arrowsize}{-10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-19\arrowsize}{10\arrowsize}}%    
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
    },
defaults = { }
}

\pgfdeclarearrow{ %page 1020 of 3.0.1a manual
name = oone,
parameters = { },
setup code = { },
drawing code = {
    \newdimen\arrowsize%
    \arrowsize=0.5pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \advance\arrowsize by .25\pgflinewidth
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-9\arrowsize}{-10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-9\arrowsize}{10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{-19\arrowsize}{0}} {6\arrowsize}%
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke%
    },
defaults = { }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}]
\draw[mmany - mmany,very thin] (0,0) -- node[above]{ mmany}node[below]{very thin} (5,0);
\draw[omany - omany] (0,-1) -- node[above]{omany}node[below]{normal size} (5,-1);
\draw[mone - mone,thick] (0,-2) -- node[above]{mone}node[below]{thick} (5,-2);
\draw[oone - oone,very thick] (0,-3) -- node[above]{ oone}node[below]{very thick} (5,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Connecting entities by using the Edge Operation

I deleted the `zig-zag` option from the `relationship` styles. This allows `edges` to be used to build `relationship arrows` between `entities` that are then simply called by their names.

```
\draw[one to omany] (A) edge  (AB);
\draw[one to omany] (B) edge  (AB);
\draw[one to one] (B) edge  (C);
\path[one to oone,zig zag] (C1) edge (C); % by default zig zag=.5
\path[one to oone,zig zag=.5 ] (C2) edge (C);%
```

---

## The result and the final code:

---

[image: diagramme]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usetikzlibrary{er}

\pgfdeclarearrow{ %page 1020 of 3.0.1a manual
name = mmany,
parameters = { },
setup code = { },
drawing code = {
    \newdimen\arrowsize%
    \arrowsize=0.5pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \advance\arrowsize by .25\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-9\arrowsize}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-13\arrowsize}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{9\arrowsize}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-19\arrowsize}{-10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-19\arrowsize}{10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
    },
defaults = { }
}

\pgfdeclarearrow{ %page 1020 of 3.0.1a manual
name = omany,
parameters = { },
setup code = { },
drawing code = {
    \newdimen\arrowsize%
    \arrowsize=0.5pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \advance\arrowsize by .25\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-9\arrowsize}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-13\arrowsize}{0pt}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{9\arrowsize}}%
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{-19\arrowsize}{0}} {6\arrowsize}%
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke%
    },
defaults = { }
}

\pgfdeclarearrow{ %page 1020 of 3.0.1a manual
name = mone,
parameters = { },
setup code = { },
drawing code = {
    \newdimen\arrowsize%
    \arrowsize=0.5pt%%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \advance\arrowsize by .25\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-9\arrowsize}{-10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-9\arrowsize}{10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-19\arrowsize}{-10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-19\arrowsize}{10\arrowsize}}%    
    \pgfusepathqstroke%
    },
defaults = { }
}

\pgfdeclarearrow{ %page 1020 of 3.0.1a manual
name = oone,
parameters = { },
setup code = { },
drawing code = {
    \newdimen\arrowsize%
    \arrowsize=0.5pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \advance\arrowsize by .25\pgflinewidth
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-9\arrowsize}{-10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-9\arrowsize}{10\arrowsize}}% 
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{-19\arrowsize}{0}} {6\arrowsize}%
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke%
    },
defaults = { }
}


\tikzset{%
    is in/.pic={\node[label=#1:is in,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt]{};},
    pics/entity/.style n args={3}{code={%
        \node[draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        text height=1.5ex,
        ] (#1)
        {#2 \nodepart{second}
            \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{8.5em}}
                #3
            \end{tabular}
        };%
    }},
    pics/entitynoatt/.style n args={2}{code={%
        \node[draw,
        text height=1.5ex,
        ] (#1)
        {#2};%
    }},
    zig zag/.style={
        to path={(\tikztostart) -| ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) |- (\tikztotarget)}
    },
    zig zag/.default=0.5, 
    one to one/.style={
        mone-mone, 
    },
    one to oone/.style={
        mone-oone
    },
    one to many/.style={
        mone-mmany,
    },
    one to omany/.style={
        mone-omany
    }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.style={ minimum width=4cm},
every second node part/.style={font=\small},
every label/.style={minimum size=0pt}
]
\pic {entity={A}{Entity A}{%
    attribute 1 \\
    attribute 2 \\        
    ... \\
    attribute i
}};
\pic at (A.north east){is in=0};
\pic[right=7em of A] {entity={AB}{Entity A for Entity B}{%
    attribute 1 \\
    attribute 2
}};
\pic[right=7em of AB] {entity={B}{Entity B}{%
    attribute 1 \\
    attribute 2 \\        
    ... \\
    attribute i
}};
\pic at (B.north west){is in=180};
\pic at (B.south east){is in=0};

\pic[below=16ex of B] {entity={C}{Entity C}{%
    attribute 1    
}};
\pic at (C.north east){is in=0};
\pic[above left=2ex and 7em of C] {entitynoatt={C1}{Entity C\_1}};
\pic[below left=2ex and 7em of C] {entitynoatt={C2}{Entity C\_2}};
\pic at (C1.north east){is in=30};
\pic at (C2.south east){is in=-30};
\draw[one to omany] (A) edge  (AB);
\draw[one to omany] (B) edge  (AB);
\draw[one to one] (B) edge  (C);
\path[one to oone,zig zag] (C1) edge (C);  
\path[one to oone,zig zag] (C2) edge (C);% 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: The option `landscape` in the `article` class means that the entire article will be `landscape`. It is not what the OP wants, see his comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462914/how-to-create-an-er-diagram-using-tikzpicture-environment#comment1166751_462914. The MWE has only one page only because it is an example.

Comment: Okay, so he can easily reuse it. I do not need to correct my answer.