# How to construct a relational database in latex for beginners

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, database

I would like to do an neat scheme of my database to pin down ideas, particularly I would like to do something like in the attached picture. Even though I have looked in internet thoroughly, I have not been able to find something similar that serves me as template in latex.

Any help, specially that regarding templates, tutorials and manuals in order of importance, would be much appreciated.

KR[image: Relational database]

Comment: The layout, lines and 2 color boxes can be done with tikz, but the internal layout of the bottom half would probably be better off using a tabular.

Comment: We generally frown on "please do this for me" requests.  Do you have a start on this, and some aspect is giving you trouble?

Comment: See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462914/how-to-create-an-er-diagram-using-tikzpicture-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1 or here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366486/crows-foot-erm-in-nice-way/367337#367337, for example.

Comment: @Teepeemm, I just didn't know how to start

Comment: but with @CarLaTex examples I think I can have a go. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: @RubénPérezSanz You're welcome! Feel free to ask any question if you meet some problems